# Android and C# tcp Connection failed

Tags: java, c#, android, wpf, tcp

I have 2 programs, one of them is android application (Client) and the other is c# wpf application (Server). My propose is to load the server, and then load the client, the client connect automatically to the server and the server identifier that it got a new client. When the server identifier a new client the server send automatically a message that contains the CliendID to the client . The client got a message from the server and then he can send to the server a message that contains the ClientID(that he got) and he's location. All of this must be in thread because I want the server and client to do other things too.The connection doesn't made, it goes to the catch with exeption "sorce not found" in both of the applications.

Client code java :

```
    //Define variables         
    String host ="192.168.43.145";           
    int port = 13000;        
    Socket socket;        
    Writer writer;        
    BufferedReader reader;

    // OnCreate function  
        socket= new Socket(host,  port);    
    writer= new  OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "latin1");    
    reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "latin1"));

// Get  reply:
    String IdObserverstring = reader.readLine();                            
    writer.write(IdObserverstring);
    writer.write(LatitudeForSend);
    writer.write(LongtitudeForSend);
    writer.flush();
```

C# code :

```
     // Define variables :
    TcpListener listenerForAndroid;    
            IPAddress ip;
            bool IsListener;    
            int port, IDObser;    
            string ipString;    
            public BinaryReader rd;    
            public MemoryStream memory;    
            public BinaryWriter wr;    
            Socket sender;

     // Constructor of application
     // Ip local host
            ipString = "192.168.43.145";  
            port = 13000();
            // Converting the ip string to ipAddress
            ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipString);  

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            listenerForAndroid = new TcpListener(ip, port);

            byte[] byteRecived = new byte[1024];

            try
            {
               // Start Listeneting at the specified port     
               listenerForAndroid.Start();
               // Now the server is running and waiting for a client connection.

               sender = listenerForAndroid.AcceptSocket(); // Client Accepted

               IDObser++;
               ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
               sender.Send(asen.GetBytes(IDObser.ToString() + "\n")); // Sending the IDObserver to the client
                int k345 = sender.Receive(byteRecived); \\ waiting for recieve ID+Location from android device

// Here I want to read from the byteRecived the bytes (all the bytes from the android device is : int(IDObserver), Double (lat), Double (long) ) but I dont know how.
```

I would be very happy to get some help . 
Thank's for helpers :)

Comment: " it goes to the catch", please show us the exception you got. You can debug it/look your logcat

Comment: I wrrited.. "Source not found"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run your C# code after small corrections (because of syntax errors) and it successfully accepts connection from TCP client and works as you expect.

First, ensure that your IPs are correct. If they are, try to debug your applications independently using some TCP debug tool (I like this one https://code.google.com/p/serialcom/ ).

I don't see why you get an exception "Source not found". My guess is that it is not an exception description but some message from your IDE (something like this: http://hmemcpy.com/2014/08/debug-symbols-dotpeek-and-long-paths-in-visual-studio/)